# Overlay HTML 5 input type file,camera with an image/text from HTML web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using HTML 5 input type controls to take capture:

```
<input type="file" id="take-picture" accept="image/*"
style="position:absolute;top:-50;left:-50;"  />
```

Using this I am able to see the camera and able to take the capture, but **I want to show text or an image on top of the camera live feed.** ?

1. How to do that
2. Is it possible to show the camera live in a div control area in HTML page?

Comment: any updates on this???

Answer (score 3):

You just have to add an overlaying div like in this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/XbZMX/   {click on 'iniciar' button}

```
#overlay{color:red;position:absolute}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I want to do it for Mobile camera(Android / iPhone / iPad), When loading camera from mobile on top of the live display need to keep a text or a transparent image. 
Is there any way to do this? 
usermedia is not supported on mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

You can show the live camera with the `getusermedia` function of HTML5. You should check this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Once you get it working, you can add some hover text with CSS. Like you do with images

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I want to do it for Mobile camera(Android / iPhone / iPad), When loading camera from mobile on top of the live display need to keep a text or a transparent image. 
Is there any way to do this on mobile browsers? 
usermedia is not supported on mobile browser