# Building web app which interacts with device cameras

Tags: mobile, web-applications, camera

I am posting this question as I would need some good advice to start building my very first app.

First, I'd like to share the aim of the app: being able to take pictures from (different) mobile devices' cameras, having a graphic (like a mask, an image) showing up when looking into the camera. The intent is to have a virtual car which I can place next to real people when shooting my pictures, see the preview and save them.

My first thought was, not to cover how to build apps for different specific devices (e.g. android, iOS, windowsphone), to make a web app. I am fairly fine with programming and web frameworks in general. Is it a reccomendable way to go?

Then, I would like some advices on the lanuages I should use. I am using a linux pc and have understanding in HTML, CSS, PHP, Python, and a bit of JavaScript. Would this be enough?

Can you point me to some useful link/tutorial?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is broad, I hope my points are specific enough to be answered without too much pain.

Comment: This looks promising... https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/capturing-images/

Comment: Other related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710724/overlay-html-5-input-type-file-camera-with-an-image-text-from-html-web-page) with good [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XbZMX/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand your question, you want to konw about web technologies wich provides you access to camera. 
Whrer is an special method, thats returns object in JS, thats can capture camera and mic data:

```
navigator.getUserMedia()
```

but it requires sequre protocol https for you server.
You should read about them. In this way, you cat get data from device's camra vai js object, and process, share it as you want.

Comment: There is a good article for this js methood:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the link. I didn't get through it yet, but it seems the examples are not working. Also, [`navigator.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) seems deprecated, and probably that's why the examples in the link are not working anymore (just a guess). Now it seems one should use the new  [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) method. Good suggestions though, thans!